# pyparsing for complex sqls

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to use the pyparsing (lib) to parse and fetch all the tables/views used in SQL statements. And I'm trying to use the select_parser.py code that is available using this pyprasing lib.

I need help in understanding what changes I have to make to the select_parser.py code to achieve the output that I have mentioned below.

I want to parse the below query and get all the tables used from the string.

```
Select
        Col 1,
        Col 2
        Col3,
        (select top 1 name from tableX) as Col4,
        col5
from
        table1 a
        left join table2 b on a.id = b.id
        right join table3 c on a.id = c.id
        left join
                (select id from table4) as d
        on c.id = d.id
```

## Expected Output

tableX,table1,table2,table3,table4

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the definition of 'identifier' as used in the comparison expression does not comprehend dot-qualified names.

Fix this by changing expr term from

```
expr_term = (
    CAST + LPAR + expr + AS + type_name + RPAR |
    EXISTS + LPAR + select_stmt + RPAR |
    function_name + LPAR + Optional(delimitedList(expr)) + RPAR |
    literal_value |
    bind_parameter |
    identifier
    )
```

to

```
expr_term = (
    CAST + LPAR + expr + AS + type_name + RPAR |
    EXISTS + LPAR + select_stmt + RPAR |
    function_name + LPAR + Optional(delimitedList(expr)) + RPAR |
    literal_value |
    bind_parameter |
    delimitedList(identifier, delim='.', combine=True)
    )
```

Comment: Ok, I tried defining optional schema and used like below  `single_source = ((database_name("database")+"."+schema_name("schema")+"."+table_name("table") |
      schema_name("schema")+"."+table_name("table") | table_name("table"))
     + 
                    Optional(Optional(AS) + table_alias("table_alias")) +
                    Optional(INDEXED + BY + index_name("name") | NOT + INDEXED)("index") | 
                  (LPAR + select_stmt + RPAR + Optional(Optional(AS) + table_alias)) | 
                  (LPAR + join_source + RPAR) )`    still I'm figuring out on joins alone.

Comment: Please put these code fragments in the body of the question, NOT in comments.  They are easier to read, and do not trigger SO's "long comment threads are not desirable" alarms.

Comment: Hi Paul, can you please help me to understand what changes I have to make to the code get the expected output. I altered the question with a more clear example.